# Google Apps Script - SetText to display array elements in a list or separate lines

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, gmail-addons

I have the following Working Code

```
function notifyNo(array1,array2,array3) {
  return CardService
     .newCardBuilder()
     .setHeader(
         CardService.newCardHeader()
             .setTitle('Draft Validation Check')
             .setSubtitle("Please validate the below recipients before sending out this message")
             .setImageStyle(CardService.ImageStyle.SQUARE)
             .setImageUrl('https://i.imgur.com/4uNXq15.png')
     )  
     .addSection(
          CardService.newCardSection()
              .setHeader('<b><font color="#FF0000">High-Risk Domains</font></b>')
              .addWidget(
                CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('<font color="#FF0000">'+array3.toString()+'</font>'))
     )
     .addSection(
          CardService.newCardSection()
              .setHeader('<b><font color="#CCCC00">Low-Risk Domains</font></b>')
              .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('<font color="#CCCC00">'+array2.toString()+'</font>'))
     )
     .addSection(
          CardService.newCardSection()
              .setHeader('<b><font color="#006400">Safe Domains</font></b>')
              .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('<font color="#006400">'+array1.toString()+'</font>'))
     )
     .build();
}
```

Which produces the below output:

[image]

I would like to:

- Make the elements presented in a list, rather than comma separated
- Is there anyway that I can control the background color for the three separate sections

Comment: I'm guessing that the background is controlled via Gmail Theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to go through each value in each array and create a paragraph widget for each.

```
function notifyNo(array1, array2, array3)
{
    var highRiskDomains = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader('<b><font color="#FF0000">High-Risk Domains</font></b>');
    array3.forEach(function(value)
    {
        highRiskDomains.addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('<font color="#FF0000">' + value + '</font>'));
    });

    var lowRiskDomains = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader('<b><font color="#CCCC00">Low-Risk Domains</font></b>');
    array2.forEach(function(value)
    {
        lowRiskDomains.addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('<font color="#CCCC00">' + value + '</font>'));
    });

    var safeDomains = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader('<b><font color="#006400">Safe Domains</font></b>');
    array1.forEach(function(value)
    {
        safeDomains.addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('<font color="#006400">' + value + '</font>'));
    });

    return CardService
        .newCardBuilder()
        .setHeader(
            CardService.newCardHeader()
                .setTitle('Draft Validation Check')
                .setSubtitle("Please validate the below recipients before sending out this message")
                .setImageStyle(CardService.ImageStyle.SQUARE)
                .setImageUrl('https://i.imgur.com/4uNXq15.png')
        )
        .addSection(highRiskDomains)
        .addSection(lowRiskDomains)
        .addSection(safeDomains)
        .build();
}
```

Comment: The OP was asking how to set the background color not the font color.

Comment: @Cooper I was addressing his first question: "Make the elements presented in a list, rather than comma separated". Since `CardService` doesn't support bullet lists, I figured this was the best approach.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan -- That does resolve the First question - Thanks a lot, I was having trouble with the syntax since this is all new to me.

Comment: @Cooper -- I'm looking for a way to control the section background style using html, but I cant seem to find a way to do so

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan -- Do you also happen to have a code to add two buttons that I can customise the action for , e.g. "Send Now" and "Go Back" buttons at the bottom of the card?

Comment: You would need to add the appropriate button widget. There is [`ImageButton`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/image-button) and [`TextButton`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-button).

Comment: Your only access to Gmail is via the card service.  So no way to access via css style that I know of.